# Robot FW : Collections library : "Copy Dictionary" : How to make a shallow copy of a compound dictionary?

Tags: robotframework

Consider the following code:

**In Utils.py:**

```
@keyword
def get_compound_dictionary():
    """
    https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html
    An example compound dictionary
    """
    return {'key1': 'value1', 'deep_dict': {'key2': 'value2'}}
```

**In collection-library-tests.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    A test suite utilizing all collection library keywords
Library          Collections
Library          Utils.py

# To run:
# robot  --pythonpath Resources --noncritical failure-expected -d Results/  Tests/collection-    
  library-tests.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Use "Copy Dictionary" : Shallow Copy
    ${compound_python_dictionary} =     get compound dictionary
    &{shallow_copy} =   Copy Dictionary     ${compound_python_dictionary}       deepcopy=False

    # if we modify the contained objects (i.e. deep_dict) through the shallow_copy,
    # the original compound_python_dictionary will see the changes in the contained objects
    Set To Dictionary    ${shallow_copy}[deep_dict]     key2=modified
    Log     ${shallow_copy}
    Log     ${compound_python_dictionary}
    Should Be Equal      ${compound_python_dictionary}[deep_dict][key2]       modified  # fails, why?
```

**The goal** is stated in the test case as:

> if we modify the contained objects (i.e. deep_dict) through the shallow_copy,
>   the original compound_python_dictionary will see the changes in the contained objects

**Expected Result**

```
Should Be Equal      ${compound_python_dictionary}[deep_dict][key2]       modified  # passes
```

**Observed Result**
[image]

> Note that I am using Robot FW version: Robot Framework 3.1.2 (Python
>   3.7.4 on linux)

Acc.to [the documentation about Copy Dictionary](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Copy%20Dictionary):

> The deepcopy argument controls should the returned dictionary be a 
>   shallow or deep copy. By default returns a shallow copy, but that can be
>   changed by giving deepcopy a true value (see **Boolean arguments**). This > is a new option in Robot Framework 3.1.2. Earlier versions always 
>   returned shallow copies.

Acc.to [the documentation about Boolean Arguments](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Boolean%20arguments):

> Some keywords accept arguments that are handled as Boolean values true or false. If such an argument is given as a string, it is considered false if it is an empty string or equal to FALSE, NONE, NO, OFF or 0, case-insensitively. Other strings are considered true regardless their value.

Note also that i tried also `deepcopy=${False}`, which yielded the same observed result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the RF keyword (it very seldom is, they have extensive UT), but with the way you call it, namely this argument:

```
deepcopy=False
```

You may be thinking you are passing a boolean value, but in fact you are passing the string `"False"`.
Inside the keyword's implementation there is this branching:

```
    if deepcopy:
        return copy.deepcopy(dictionary)
```

, and as a non-empty string evaluates to `True`, you are in fact getting a deep copy.

This is the way to pass a real `False`:

```
deepcopy=${False}
```

Comment: I updated the ticket based on the instructions of your comment. Long story short, deepcopy=${False} wont work either. Can run this code on your machine? Thanks Todor.

Comment: "Some keywords accept arguments that are handled as Boolean ... " - this one does not, check its implementation.  https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/src/robot/libraries/Collections.py#L563  I cannot run your code anytime soon, but will be deeply surprised if it misbehaves with proper boolean false.

Comment: I admit that the code link you provided indeed says differently than what the documentation for the keyword say. So, one issue is a conflict between code and its documentation. Another issue is that given the code you provided, deepcopy=${False} is not working (i deleted all the test logs and re-run the test case twice). What is the reason??

Comment: Off topic, but I don't see how the documentation of the keyword differs from its implementation; it describes precisely what the keyword does.

Comment: The documentation of the keyword says that deepcopy=False or deepcopy=${False} will be considered as falsy values, therefore shallow copying will take place. Note that i updated this ticket with the keywords documentation.